# How to run concurring SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am trying to run this sql query.

```
SELECT * FROM AverageFeedInfo WHERE No = (
SELECT No FROM UserResponse2 where Not Complain = '' )
```

When I run `SELECT No FROM UserResponse2 where Not Complain = ''` individually I have result `2 and 6`, but if I run this

```
SELECT * FROM AverageFeedInfo WHERE No = (
SELECT No FROM UserResponse2 where Not Complain = '' )
```

I have only the result for 2 not for 6. Is it possible to get the answer for both 2 and 6. To be more clear is it possible to run the sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM AverageFeedInfo WHERE No = 2 or No = 6
```

Comment: Which is it, MySQL or SQLite? Use `IN` instead of `=`; I'd be a little surprised if MySQL actually executed the query without error.

Comment: I am trying to doing this in SQLite.

Comment: @Uueerdo hey Thanks I am running SELECT * FROM AverageFeedInfo WHERE No IN (SELECT No FROM UserResponse2 where Not Complain = '') and it solve the problem.. ;)

Comment: Posted as an answer so it can be marked accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when checking set membership in a SQL-based context use of an `IN` operator is more appropriate than `=`.